# Heroku deployment error H10; Error: Cannot find module '/app/console`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my first React application on Heroku. The Build portion appears successful, but launching the app delivers a white screen with "Application error."

I've followed heroku logs --tail, but cannot identify the errors that it is giving me.

Heroku logs --tail:

```
2019-05-30T13:15:28.528598+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=serene-peak- 
12902.herokuapp.com request_id=e2d2bd7d-9b96-42fb-a4ce-89cc7bccfad6 
fwd="67.166.97.166" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
protocol=https
2019-05-30T13:15:29.101530+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=serene-peak- 
12902.herokuapp.com request_id=44fa674d-ef39-4132-9c6f-430038be66ec 
fwd="67.166.97.166" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
protocol=https
```

Heroku run node console:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:550
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/console'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
```

Comment: It looks like the error is on line 548 of your loader.js and it seems to be that it cannot find the module called /app/console

Comment: Maybe you can try to put a dot before the path, like so: `./app/console` ?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're using stack MERN) Heroku can't find the root path. You have to get your Express app to serve your React app,  so you need to config your server.js file in order to do that.

[Follow this tutorial](https://coursework.vschool.io/deploying-mern-with-heroku/)